# Wordpress import process ends in 502 Bad Gateway error

Tags: nginx, wordpress, import, 502-error

I have a Wordpress website which have been working flawlessly for a while now in a LEMP with Ubuntu.

However, today I had to import a previously exported XML from another Wordpress and in the middle of the process I get the 502 Bad Gateway error.

Checking `error.log`, I see this:

```
2020/08/29 00:16:48 [error] 7#7: *954359 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: 189.11.0.19, server: example.com, request: "POST /wp-admin/admin.php?import=wordpress&step=2 HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://189.11.0.19:9001", host: "example.com", referrer: "https://example.com/wp-admin/admin.php?import=wordpress&step=1&_wpnonce=ef40a27516"
```

Why this happens? How can I fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Warm regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This usually happens if your import is large and PHP runs into its execution time limit.

You can restart the import and it will pick up where it left off. Depending on the size of the import, you may have to do this several times.

Alternatively, you can increase PHP's `max_execution_time` in `php.ini`, but even so you'll probably end up restarting the import several times anyway.

Comment: Well, that worked out smoothly. Thanks!